# Using GTFS real time feed

Tags: gtfs, opentripplanner

I am trying to use GTFS real time updates and have otp version - otp-0.19.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar but, it doesn't have Configuration.md file which contains  router-config.json. Please suggest how can i get a newer version of otp jar file or can include this configuration file to the existing version.

Answer (score 1):

The jar should not contain the `router-config.json`, since you might have more than one in the same server (one per router).

But you should not have a problem creating your own. Here is an example:

```
{
  "updaters": [
      {
        "type": "real-time-alerts",
        "sourceType": "gtfs-http",
        "frequencySec": 10,
        "url": "http://my-rt-fee-publisher.com/feeds",
        "defaultAgencyId": "Agency name"
      }
  ]
}
```

Drop this file in the same folder of your GTFS zip and OSM data and OTP will take care of using it to update the graph.